# Grouping by year and month with MySQL while leveraging indexes and avoiding temporary/filesort

Tags: mysql, date, query-optimization, aggregate

I have a large dataset (which is going to keep on growing!) where the data being read in bulk is stored with a `DATE` column, as all rows in any of the core data tables belong to a specific day (context is analytics/reporting).

A lot of the views require data on a per month rather than per day detail level, and I'm aggregating the data as needed via SQL (SUM, AVG, etc).

This also means I'm grouping data by `YEAR()` and `MONTH()`, which cannot use the index on the `DATE` column and results in a `Use temporary` and `Use filesort` from the query executor.

Is the best solution here to split the `DATE` column into 3 separate columns for year, month and day? Or to retain the `DATE` column (constraint, sorting, etc) and have a "yearmonth" (yyyymm) column which is also indexed? I don't like duplicating data but I'm just not 100% on what would be the best practice for this scenario.

Comment: Best solution in terms of what? Generally, the best solution is to store the date, and leave it at that.

Comment: Just because use temporary and use filesort show up doesn't mean that your queries will perform poorly.  Do you have proof they're slow?  If you're looking for another option instead of a DATE column, consider using an integer column and store an epoch based numeric timestamp in it

Answer (score 1):

Do not split a DATE into component parts.  The difficulties outweighs the presumed benefit.

Use Summary Tables to avoid lengthy analytics/reporting.  See [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) on such.  Roughly speaking, every night you would calculate some subtotals and counts for the past day, and put these in a "Summary Table".  Analytics would run much faster against that table than against the "Fact" table.

For AVG, be sure to store SUM() and COUNT(*), the compute (in the Report) `SUM(sums) / SUM(counts) as Average`.

Comment: What if you need the summary table to have data summarized in real time? Meaning, there are many records in the original data table been inserted constantly and the summary table needs to be up to date. Mantaining and updating the summary table could become a bottleneck right? What solution would you advice in that case?

Comment: @tommyalvarez - My blog discusses what to do to keep it up to date with IODKU or "as-needed".

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way in terms of performance with `GROUP`-ing and `SELECT`-ing on month and date columns is to add a `MONTH` and `YEAR` column to the data. The speed you gain by proper index usage will outnumber the pain of some more / duplicated data.

Note that there is a `YEAR` datatype in MySQL.

Make sure to use `B-TREE` indices on `month` and `year` column (not `HASH`).